# Python GDAL does not install on Mac OSX El Capitan

Tags: python, macos, osx-elcapitan, gdal

I am having several issues when installing pygdal in my Mac OSX El capitan. The procedure is the folowing:

1. Install GDAL Libraries from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks#gdal_complete
2. `pip install gdal`

The output is the following:

```
.
.
.
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3085:10: fatal error: 'cpl_port.h' file not found

    #include "cpl_port.h"
         ^
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Looks like the installer cannot find the GDAL libraries, or headers (libgdal or gdal-devel in ubuntu).

Where are they placed in OSX?

FYI, the following `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs` is into the `$PATH` variable.

Comment: El Capitan as part of increased security puts system files in different places. A number of mainstream programs have been broken by this. I can not find any file cpl_port.h on my Mac should that help.

Comment: I did a `sudo find / -name cpl_port.h` and got this: `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Headers/cpl_port.h
/opt/local/include/cpl_port.h`. I added those directories to my PATH but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Hey !!! Sorry..now it worked !!... I put wrong the path int $PATH.

Comment: Easily done.   Well, if it also works as a solution to your original question, I suggest write it up as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally (with a little help from [Cam_Aust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389320/cam-aust)) solved the problem !!!

Here is what I did:

1. Find the cp_port.h file in your system: `sudo find / -name cpl_port.h`, My output was:

`/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Headers/cpl_port.h      /opt/local/include/cpl_port.h`

2. Add the resulting folders to your $PATH in your bash init script (~/.bash_login or ~/.zshrc). This worked for me: `export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Headers:$PATH`
3. Open a new terminal session or `source ~/.zshrc`

After this, you can now `pip install gdal`:

```
Collecting gdal 
Using cached GDAL-2.1.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: gdal
Running setup.py install for gdal ... done
Successfully installed gdal-2.1.0
```

Comment: Excellent, here now for others.

Comment: Despite adding the path variables to my .bash_profile, I still get the 'cpl_port.h' error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @ToneDaBass - this answer didn't work for me either (macos sierra, python 2.7 in virtualenv), see below for the fix that did work

Answer (score 2):

After installing the GDAL Libraries from kyngchaos (as mentioned in the question) you should be able to find the python package ready to go.

I cheated and used that:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Python/2.7/site-packages
```