# Incompatible library version when importing GDAL on macOS

Tags: python, macos, gdal, osgeo

I am trying to install import a `gdal` library.

```
from osgeo import ogr
```

but I get the following error

```
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libtiff.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libgdal.20.dylib requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libtiff.5.dylib provides version 8.0.0
```

I installed `gdal` trough `conda install gdal`

Comment: Maybe try `ulimit -n 2048` or somesuch.

Comment: how did you install `osgeo` and/or `gdal`? How did you install python3? Note that on Mac OS python 2.7.2 is installed by default. This error is clearly a dependency issue so something went wrong during installation or package dependencies are broken.

Comment: @MarekR I installed `gdal` trough `conda`.  but I don't remember how I installed `python3`. I know that there is some error.

Comment: Can you try to update the libtiff library ?

Comment: This issue has been solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700484/python-gdal-does-not-install-on-mac-osx-el-capitan

Comment: I'm not familiar with `conda` anyway I'm sure problem is in package definition or installation of package was unsuccessful. Maybe you can try force installation of `libtiff` in required version.

Comment: @MarekR I am trying to install it

Comment: Now I get another error : `ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpoppler.71.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
  Reason: image not found
`

Comment: Some progress. Looks like you are using some unofficial package repository, since when I'm inspecting coda repositories I see [much older versions of `libtiff`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/libtiff).

Comment: @MarekR now I have installed it and I get the errore above `ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpoppler.71.dylib Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/libgdal.20.dylib Reason: image not found`